# Data retrieval/storage & graphing solution selection

Tags: php, graph, snmp, rrdtool, cacti

Our company have a need to set up some solution, that would allow us to grap *almost live* (1 second interval) data, from electrical equipment. Currently, the thing we are using, is Cacti, which allows lowest read interval to 1 minute.

What would be your software solution suggestion, for such a situation, considering, that data is retrieved by SNMP, XML or web interface (ther's more than one device, each with different data retrieval method) and my knowlage covers HTML\PHP\JavaScript programming capabilities. As *nix CRON can handle only 1 minute intervals as minimum, there should be some tool or solution, that could "ask" by itself. Only workaround I see, is to code some JavaScript, that is reloading every second, triggering server-side code.

Maybe, there are some ready-solutions like RRDTool or maybe, using ordinary MySQL+Graph library (Google, etc) will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a time-series data, RRDTool is the best solution for this. But you need RRDTool knowledge for this.

RRDTool allows data/per second. But Cacti works over *nix cron. And cron works at least every 1 minute (tell me if im wrong). You need a special coding for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "RRDTool knowlage"? Any particular?

Comment: Yes you need to know terminology of RRD's. (Creating, updating and graphing knowledge) First you need create it from cli, and also write a script for updating RRD's every second.

Comment: No problem with that. Goint through Cacti, I already have got through RRDTool documentation. Some stuff about construction for RRDs, are still unknown, but I hope, that wont be an issue...

Comment: On pure SNMP you've got MRTG which is built on the top of RRDTools. It consists of a Perl script which uses SNMP to read the traffic counters of your routers and a fast C program which logs the traffic data and creates beautiful graphs representing the traffic on the monitored network connection. These graphs are embedded into webpages which can be viewed from any modern Web-browser. Perhaps you can adapt it to your aother sources.